# Leaflet : only display blank page

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app using Cordova, Leaftlet and Ionic.

Here is my code in controllers.js :

```
//map
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicNavBarDelegate, geolocation, notif) {
    // Change the title bar content
    $scope.viewTitle = "<img src='img/map.svg' class='nav-title-icon'/>Confirmer la position";

    $scope.initMap = function() {
        var map = new L.map('map');
        var osmURL = 'http://{s}.hide/hide/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        var osmAttrib = 'Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors';
        var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, { attribution: osmAttrib });

        map.setView(new L.LatLng(47.12, 01.13), 11);
        map.addLayer(osm);
    }
});
```

And my html code for the map state :

```
<ion-view title="MAP">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-checkmark-round stable" ng-click="confirmPosition()"></button> 
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When I emulate my app using `cordova emulate ios` it displays a blank page with no header with title and a green footer.

[HERE](http://hpics.li/00bef1b)

If I put my $scope.initMap = function() on commentary it displays a blank page with my blue header and title (and no green footer).

[HERE](http://hpics.li/d950924)

This is the first time I work with js, cordova and ionic. Can you give me some tips please ?

Thank you !